# Get value of a data attribute and show it in a modal in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `Bootstrap v.3.3.7` and in my page I have placed a lot of buttons which work to show `modal`. Inside the `modal` I have placed a `popover` button.

```
<a href="#" id="open1" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="1" rel="popover" data-target="Message">open modal 1</a>
```

Using `jQuery`, I get the value of `data-id` attribute and I try to show this value as popover text.

```
  var btnid = 0;
  $('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    btnid = $(this).attr('data-id');
  });

  var textToShow = 'click ' + btnid;

  $('.stopMachine').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'toggle',
    content: textToShow
  });
```

However, I get `click 0` in all cases...

```js
$(function() {
  $('#open1').click(function() {
    $('#myModal1').modal('show')
  });

  $('#open2').click(function() {
    $('#myModal2').modal('show')
  });

  var btnid = 0;

  $('.stopMachine').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'toggle',
    content: function() {
      $('.stopMachine').click(function() {
        btnid = $(this).data('id');
        console.log("btnid = " + btnid);
      });
      var message = 'click ' + btnid;
      return message;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" id="open1" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-target="Message">open modal 1</a>

<a href="#" id="open2" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-message="Message">open modal 2</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success stopMachine" data-id="1" rel="popover" data-message="Message">info</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success stopMachine" data-id="2" rel="popover" data-message="Message">info</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I moved the `data-attribute` inside the link in the modal. However, it doesn't get the value in the 1st click, but in the 2nd!

Comment: Don't read data via attr. Try doing it by $(this).data('id');

Comment: `btnid` is `0` by the time `popover()` is called because the button is not yet clicked.

Comment: @Tushar I got your point! I updated my question. Now the text is updated in the 2nd click!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `data-content` attribute instead of the popover property, you initiate the popover at page ready:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#open1').click(function() {
    $('#myModal1').modal('show');
    $('#myModal1 .stopMachine').attr('data-content',"click "+$(this).attr('data-id'));
  });

  $('#open2').click(function() {
    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
    $('#myModal2 .stopMachine').attr('data-content',"click "+$(this).attr('data-id'));
  });


  $('.stopMachine').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'toggle',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" id="open1" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="1" rel="popover" data-target="Message">open modal 1</a>

<a href="#" id="open2" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="2" rel="popover" data-message="Message">open modal 2</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success stopMachine" rel="popover" data-message="Message">info</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success stopMachine" rel="popover" data-message="Message">info</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for your modified code you don't need any click event, you need to do the following

```js
$('#open1').click(function() {
  $('#myModal1').modal('show')
});

$('#open2').click(function() {
  $('#myModal2').modal('show')
});

$('.stopMachine').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-content', "click " + $(this).attr('data-id'));
})

$('.stopMachine').popover({
  placement: 'right',
  html: true,
  trigger: 'toggle',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" id="open1" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-target="Message">open modal 1</a>

<a href="#" id="open2" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" data-message="Message">open modal 2</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success stopMachine" data-id="1" rel="popover" data-message="Message">info</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success stopMachine" data-id="2" rel="popover" data-message="Message">info</a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use the `$('#open1').click(function() { ...` just here to open the modal.. In my actual implementation, the modals are open without that. I only have the `$('.stopMachine').popover({` statement...

Comment: then you need move the code outside the click events,

Comment: Could you help me with that? I altered my question but the text is updated in the second click..

Comment: what's the use of the second click?

Comment: None use. I just noticed that the text is updated after the 2nd click..

Comment: see the second part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

please replace your jquery code with this. hope it will be helpful. please see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/pz0ucaks/2/)

```
var click=0;
$(function() {
  $('#open1').click(function() {
    $('#myModal1').modal('show')
  });

  $('#open2').click(function() {
    $('#myModal2').modal('show')
  });

  var btnid = 0;
  $('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    btnid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log("btnid = " + btnid);
    var textToShow = 'click ' + btnid;
    if(click>0){$('.stopMachine').popover('destroy');}
    $('.stopMachine').popover({
      placement: 'right',
      html: true,
      trigger: 'toggle',
      content: textToShow
    });
    click++;
  });     
});
```

Comment: i have working example as per your given code @yaylitzis